# BeautifulSoup bsObj.find("title") fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am new to python web scraping,,using BeautifulSoup to try to parser a web and send mail,however,,,I think it is about when I try to parser the web has some parameter mistake,,,
I can get the mail,,however,,
I always get the mail "It's not Joe",,
but the web shows Joe,,,
How can I can the mail "it is Joe"?? 
thanks for anyone who answer me! I use python3,,the web side http://www.douban.com/people/25698302/

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time

def sendMail(subject, body):
    msg = MIMEText(body)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = "myMialServer@myms.com"
    msg['To'] = "toMyAmail@myAmail.com"

    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.send_message(msg)
    s.quit()

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("http://www.douban.com/people/25698302/"))
while(bsObj.find("title") == "Joe"):
    sendMail("it is Joe!","It's Joe")

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("http://www.douban.com/people/25698302/"))
sendMail("It's not Joe","It's not Joe")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious inference is that your `while` loop condition is false the first time it is evaluated, so the loop body executes zero times.

A little experimentation shows that the value of `bsObj.find("title")` is

```
<title>
Joe
</title>
```

which clearly evaluates as not equal to `"Joe"`. You will also find that `bsObj.find("title").text` is `"\nJoe\n"` which is close to what you are testing for.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you don't want to use a `while`. A `while` is a loop, which implies that your code will keep sending the email for "It's Joe" continuously (infinite loop) as the `bsObj` variable won't change inside the loop.

Next, if you print out `bsObj.find("title")` you find the output to be:

```
<title>
Joe
</title>
```

So, it is not equal to "Joe". Which is why that while loop always fails.
You could use `bsObj.find('title').text().strip()` to get what you want.